# Cooling down from −78 °C to −88 °C without cryogenics

Tags: energy, enthalpy, heat, temperature, liquids

Say I have a gas cylinder with nitrous oxide and cool it down to −78 °C with dry ice. Is there an endothermic process/reaction that would extract the remaining heat from $\ce{N2O}$ and bring it down by 10 °C to its boiling point of −88 °C? I know this could be done by using cryogenics like liquid nitrogen, but I want to avoid those.

Comment: you could let out a little bit of the gas the pressure drops and it cools down

Comment: At -78C the N2O vapor pressure is only 1.8 bar - do you think it would be enough just to let that out?

Comment: a dry ice/ether cooling bath will get you below -90C

Comment: When dealing with pressurised gases, it is usually better to let the gas flow into a cold place rather than cooling the cylinder. Not least because the gas will still have enough pressure to get out of the cylinder.